# Java Header not displayed

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee

i am inclduing a header.jsp in my layout.sp but it does not get reflected in the browser and have tried both mozilla and ie even after refreshing cache..

header.jsp content---

```
<h1>Login Application</h1>
```

layout.jsp content--

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<%@ taglib uri="http://www.opensymphony.com/sitemesh/decorator"
    prefix="decorator"%>

<%@page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"%>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
<head>
<title></title>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />


</head>

<body>
<div>
 <jsp:include page="/WEB-INF/includes/header.jsp"/>
</div>


<div  ><decorator:body /></div>



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why in the world is this tagged java and eclipse? Looks more like javascript and browser!

Comment: @Chris it's a JSP problem, thus java was at least correct. I've re-tagged it.

Comment: What is the output if you just try to load "/WEB-INF/includes/header.jsp" in the browser?  My suspicion is that the path to the include is incorrect.

Comment: it gives "The requested resource (/LoginFinal/WEB-INF/includes/header.jsp) is not available.


--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
"

Answer (score 3):

It's because it's in the WEB-INF directory.

Everything that is in the WEB-INF isn't accessible to the HTTP server.  A `jsp:include` is called via an  HTTP request to the server but the target file is something it is not allowed to serve, so you get nothing.

If you really want to use that file as is, you can use this:

```
 <%@ include file="/WEB-INF/includes/header.jsp" %>
```

as that will get evaluated at compile time and the compiler is able to access that file.

Or you could move the jsp to a file that is accessible to the web server, like `/includes/` that is a sibling to `WEB-INF.`

```
<jsp:include page="/includes/header.jsp"/>
```

Also, make sure the file has the proper permissions so the server can access it.